# R: How to convert an xts object to a numeric matrix?

Tags: r, dataframe, xts

I need to convert an xts matrix to a numeric matrix or a data.frame with numeric columns, whatever works. I've tried using data.matrix() but the results are still in character format:

```
class(myxts)
[1] "xts" "zoo"
class(myxts[, "MyNumericColumn"]
[1] "xts" "zoo"

myxts.num = data.matrix(myxts)
class(myxts.num[, "MyNumericColumn"]
[1] "character"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This does the trick although I'm not sure what the performance penalty is:

```
mynumeric.matrix = data.matrix(as.data.frame(myxts))
```

The call to as.data.frame converts all strings to numeric values, then data.matrix() returns the matrix changing all remaining strings to NAs.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this is what you're asking but I did

```
require(YieldCurve)
data(FedYieldCurve)
august <- FedYieldCuve['2011-08']
unclass(august)[1,]
```

The `unclass` being the function that does what I think you want to do (remove the `xts`-specific `attr`'s and only use the numbers). The rest being some sample data.

Comment: This answer worked like a charm for me in a similar situation. I think `unclass` is the most straightforward option here.